# While importing pandas_profiling getting ImportError: cannot import name 'VisionsTypeset' from 'visions' (unknown location)

Tags: python, installation, pandas-profiling

I am trying to run `import pandas_profiling` but getting error `ImportError: cannot import name 'VisionsTypeset' from 'visions' (unknown location)`. I have tried installing `pip install visions` and `pip install visions[all]` which gets installed but I still get the same error.

Complete Error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 5
      2 import pandas as pd
      4 # from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings
----> 5 import pandas_profiling

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas_profiling\__init__.py:8
      1 """Main module of pandas-profiling.
      2 
      3 .. include:: ../../README.md
      4 """
      6 from warnings import warn
----> 8 from pandas_profiling.compare_reports import compare
      9 from pandas_profiling.controller import pandas_decorator
     10 from pandas_profiling.profile_report import ProfileReport

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas_profiling\compare_reports.py:8
      6 from pandas_profiling.config import Correlation, Settings
      7 from pandas_profiling.model.alerts import Alert
----> 8 from pandas_profiling.profile_report import ProfileReport
     11 def _should_wrap(v1: Any, v2: Any) -> bool:
     12     if isinstance(v1, (list, dict)):

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas_profiling\profile_report.py:11
...
---> 11 from visions import VisionsTypeset
     13 from pandas_profiling.config import Config, Settings
     14 from pandas_profiling.expectations_report import ExpectationsReport

ImportError: cannot import name 'VisionsTypeset' from 'visions' (unknown location)
```